# SlidesJS Pause Workaround?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I downloaded and successfully implemented this new plugin named SlidesJS. The slides ran perfectly in the auto-play mode. However, I seemed to notice a problem(not sure if its a problem or a feature). Whenever I clicked a pagination item, the auto-slide effect pauses. I will not be showing the play button on screen, and hence this will be a problem. I want the auto-slide effect to continue even after the user clicks on the pagination items.

Is there a solution to this ?

Comment: can u simulate the same on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @dreamweiver I hope this helps. Its present on the actual site..

http://www.slidesjs.com/examples/playing/

Can a solution be achieved ?

Comment: By pagination you mean  navigating manually using next and prev icons right ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following complete callback in your options (using SlidesJS 3.0):

```
$('#slides').slidesjs({
    callback: {
        complete: function(number) {
            var pluginInstance = $('#slides').data('plugin_slidesjs');

            setTimeout(function() {
                pluginInstance.play(true);
            }, pluginInstance.options.play.interval);
        }
    }
});
```